# MacOS SwiftUI App extremely slow on start

Tags: swift, macos, performance, swiftui

I'm building a swiftUI macOS app that involves a stopwatch. When I start the stopwatch for the 1st time after launching the app, it runs very slowly, increasing by 1 second every few seconds. Time profiler shows that during this time CPU usage spikes to and remains as about 100%. When I stop the stopwatch, it goes back to normal, and starting it again, it runs at normal speed.

Here is my code for the stopwatch, I don't think there's anything wrong with it?

```
class TimerManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var secondsElapsed = 0.0
    @Published var isRunning = false
    var timer = Timer()
    
    func start() {
        isRunning = true
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.01, repeats: true) { timer in
            self.secondsElapsed += 0.01
        }
    }
    
    func stop() {
        timer.invalidate()
        isRunning = false
    }
    
    func reset() {
        secondsElapsed = 0
    }
}
```

It's the only code I can think of that might be useful to share. I'm pretty sure the code that starts and stops it is fine, since I tried replacing it with 2 normal buttons and the problem persists.

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know what thread you are calling it from?

Comment: Maybe the main thread? I didn’t specify any thread I don’t think.

Comment: To make a suggestion that wouldn't affect performance, but would improve the accuracy of the timer, I would recommend something like `startTime = Date()` to mark the time when you start the timer, and use `Date().timeIntervalSince(startTime)` to calculate the time elapsed instead of adding a fixed increment.  The reason is that you're not guaranteed that the timer will fire exactly on time.  It might be slightly delayed from the time interval you specify.

Comment: As for the performance, if you're Time Profile in Instruments, the info in the bottom half of the window will help you figure how where it's spending all the time.   That info will be helpful in figuring out what is eating up so many CPU cycles while the timer is started.

Comment: Can you show the code where you call startTimer() from and also where you are updating the view?

Comment: Yeah I’ll do that once I get home in a few hours. I’m planning on using the start time like chip said, and also only showing 1 decimal while the timer is running to help performance. Also, what exactly should I be looking at in time profiler? I don’t know much about how to use it.

Comment: I believe I figured out the problem! I just changed the timer to only update 10 times per second and the issue seems to have gone away